# What is the difference in the below example

Tags: python, class

```
Class Explain:
    Pass

X = Explain()
Y = Explain
```

What is the difference between X And Y in the above example?

Comment: I think you meant to start with class Explain(): Pass if this is python. What have you explored. Hint: what type is X? what type is Y? what type is Explain?

Comment: i know X in an instance of EXPLAIN class, but what is the use of Y in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

In `Python` everything is treated as object be it class or function. In the above case `X` is the instance/object of class `Explain` and `Y` is the class object itself.

Comment: i know X in an instance of EXPLAIN class, but what is the use of Y in the above code?

Comment: @baluk if you have class level variables or functions e.g. `static` variables in `C++` then you can use class variable to access and initialize them.